# Merge columns equal FullCalendar

Tags: php

Good afternoon guys, I have a calendar in php, seeking information in the database.
And I would like the inserted appointment, were merged from the beginning to the end of it.
Same as google calendar.

See the image below. That's my current view of the calendar.

[image]

Notice the "Teste Evento 1" and "Teste Evento 3" events.
I would like to stay in the image below.

[image]

Code:

```
$data = date('d/m/y');
$data_explode = explode("/", $data);

$dia = $data_explode[0];
$mes = $data_explode[1];
$ano = $data_explode[2];
$calendario = "";

$v_mes = substr($mes, 0, 2);
$novo_mes = (int) $mes - 1;

$ultimo_dia_mes = date("t", mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes, 1, $ano));

$vetor_dias_semana = array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

$vetor_mes = array("Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Mar&ccedil;o", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julho", "Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro");

$calendario .="<div class='cabecalho_semana'>Domingo</div><div class='cabecalho_semana'>Segunda</div><div class='cabecalho_semana'>Terça</div><div class='cabecalho_semana'>Quarta</div><div div class='cabecalho_semana'>Quinta</div><div class='cabecalho_semana'>Sexta</div><div class='cabecalho_semana'>Sábado</div>";
$contador = 1;

$dia_semana_primeiro_dia = $dia_semana = date("w", mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes, 1, $ano));

$trava = "F";
$inicio = 1;

for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
    if ($dia_semana_primeiro_dia == $i || $trava == "T") {


        $dados = connection::select("select * from agenda where (data_agenda <= '$ano-$mes-$inicio' AND termino_agenda >= '$ano-$mes-$inicio')");
        //$dados = connection::select("select * from agenda as a inner join agendap as p on a.id_agenda = p.agenda_agendap where p.pessoa_agendap = $id_pessoa AND a.data_agenda = '$ano-$mes-$inicio' or a.termino_agenda = '$ano-$mes-$inicio'");
        $reg = $dados->fetchObject();

        if (!empty($reg)) {
            $compromisso = '<small>';

            $d = connection::select("select * from agenda where (data_agenda <= '$ano-$mes-$inicio' AND termino_agenda >= '$ano-$mes-$inicio')");

            foreach ($d as $r) {
                $compromisso .= '#' . $r['id_agenda'] . ' - ' . $r['compromisso_agenda'] . '<br>';
            }
            $compromisso .= '</small>';

            $calendario .="<div style='background-color:#fff;' class='cabecalho_dia' value='$ano-$mes-$inicio'><a href=" . URL . "agenda/data/$ano-$mes-$inicio>" . $inicio . "<br><font style='color:#fff;background-color:#166C25;'>" . $compromisso . "</font></a></div>";
        }
        else {
            $calendario .="<div style='background-color:#fff;' class='cabecalho_dia' value='$ano-$mes-$inicio'><a href=" . URL . "agenda/data/$ano-$mes-$inicio>" . $inicio . "</a></div>";
        }
        $trava = "T";
        $inicio++;
    }
    else {
        $calendario .="<div style='background-color:#fff;' class='cabecalho_dia'>&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>";
    }
}

$fim = "F";
$linha_semana = 1;
while ($fim == "F" || $linha_semana < 6) {

    for ($f = 0; $f < 7; $f++) {

        $linha_semana++;

        if ($inicio <= $ultimo_dia_mes) {

            $dados2 = connection::select("select * from agenda where (data_agenda <= '$ano-$mes-$inicio' AND termino_agenda >= '$ano-$mes-$inicio')");
            //$dados2 = connection::select("select * from agenda as a inner join agendap as p on a.id_agenda = p.agenda_agendap where p.pessoa_agendap = $id_pessoa and data_agenda = '$ano-$mes-$inicio' or a.termino_agenda = '$ano-$mes-$inicio'");
            $reg2 = $dados2->fetchObject();

            if (!empty($reg2)) {
                $compromisso = '<small>';

                $d = connection::select("select * from agenda where (data_agenda <= '$ano-$mes-$inicio' AND termino_agenda >= '$ano-$mes-$inicio')");

                foreach ($d as $r) {
                    $compromisso .= '#' . $r['id_agenda'] . ' - ' . $r['compromisso_agenda'] . '<br>';
                }
                $compromisso .= '</small>';

                $calendario .="<div style='background-color:#fff;' class='cabecalho_dia' value='$inicio/$mes/$ano'><a href=" . URL . "agenda/data/$ano-$mes-$inicio>" . $inicio . "<br><font style='color:#fff;background-color:#166C25;'>" . $compromisso . "</font></div>";
            }
            else {
                $calendario .="<div style='background-color:#fff;' class='cabecalho_dia' value='$inicio/$mes/$ano'><a href=" . URL . "agenda/data/$ano-$mes-$inicio>" . $inicio . "</a></div>";
            }

            if ($inicio == $ultimo_dia_mes) {
                $fim = "T";
            }
            $inicio++;
        }
        else {
            $calendario .="<div style='background-color:#fff;' class='cabecalho_dia'>&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>";
        }
    }
}

$html = str_replace('#CALENDARIO#', $calendario, $html);
```